# Clarkson Keystroke Dynamics dataset

Tags: data-request, computing

I'm reading in this article ([Shared Research Dataset to Support Development of Keystroke Authentication](https://www.clarkson.edu/sites/default/files/2017-11/Shared%20Research%20Dataset.pdf)) that Clarkson university has released a dataset with user keystrokes and timing information.

However, [the link to the dataset](http://clarkson.edu/citer/research/%20collections/index.html) has expired. Does anyone know where I can find this dataset?

Comment: Have you tried emailing CITeR at Clarkson University? https://citer.clarkson.edu/research-resources/biometric-dataset-collections-2/clarkson-university-keystroke-dataset/